# ListView_FindItem поиск элемента в окне чужого процесса

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Выделяю память в чужем процессе через VirtualAllocEx, записываю в неё LVFINDINFOA, вызываю ListView_FindItem, но он постоянно возвращает -1

```
#include <Windows.h> 
#include <Commctrl.h> 

#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HWND h = 0;
    char* name = "chrome.exe";
    size_t name_s = strlen(name) + 1;


    h = FindWindowA(NULL, "Диспетчер задач Windows");

    DWORD PID = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(h, &PID);
    HANDLE mem = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, PID);
    LPVOID strptr = VirtualAllocEx(mem, NULL, name_s, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    cout << "write=" << WriteProcessMemory(mem, (LPVOID)strptr, name, name_s, NULL) << endl;

    LVFINDINFOA l;
    l.flags = LVFI_STRING;
    l.psz = (char*)strptr;


    LPVOID foptr = VirtualAllocEx(mem, NULL, sizeof(LVFINDINFOA), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    cout << "write=" << WriteProcessMemory(mem, (LPVOID)foptr, &l, sizeof(LVFINDINFOA), NULL) << endl;
    h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, NULL, "Процессы");
    h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "SysListView32", NULL);

    int i = ListView_FindItem(h, -1, strptr);
    cout << "index=" << i << endl;
    cout << "err=" << GetLastError() << endl;
}
```

Comment: А попробуйте выделять память в своем процессе, есть у меня подозрение что не может оно вот так в чужой писать...